# if check nesting c sharp

Tags: c#

I have code where i must check if a variable has the value of variable a or b.
also like this

```
    public void test(int c){   
     int a= 1; 
     int b = 2; 
      if(c == (a ||b)){
     .....
       }
```

if there a problems how I worded my question, let me know.

Comment: `if (c == a || c == b)`

Comment: I must worded It wrong I know this option but my variable name of c is quite long, so that the If check is quit long.

Comment: Then break it over two lines, or see some of the answers in the linked question (although those will be significantly more expensive to run)

Comment: thanks fo the link, this is really helps.